# Password input for PNotify prompt

Tags: jquery, pnotify

I want to use a PNotify prompt dialog for entering a password. Does anyone know how to change the input type to be password? I can't see any mention of it in the docs. http://jsfiddle.net/gusLfnux/1/

```
new PNotify({
  title: 'Password Required',
  text: 'Enter Password',
  icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-lock',
  styling: 'bootstrap3',
  hide: false,
  addclass: 'stack-modal',
  confirm: {
    prompt: true
  },
  buttons: {
    closer: false,
    sticker: false
  },
  history: {
    history: false
  }
})
```

Comment: Can you please show us your code? HTML also please. A minimal working example to see what you're trying to do.

Comment: I haven't added any custom HTML to it. When a button is clicked PNotify opens the prompt. There examples can be seen here https://sciactive.github.io/pnotify/#demos-simple

Comment: Where is the input. I don't see any input. You mean you want to add an input of type password inside the notify popup?

Comment: If you search for prompt dialog. There is two examples

Comment: Yes that's right I want to  add an input of type password inside the notify popup

Comment: Can you please create a https://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: Sure http://jsfiddle.net/gusLfnux/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to get the result I wanted by adding a custom css class to the confirm object. Working example http://jsfiddle.net/gusLfnux/2/

css:

```
.password {
   -webkit-text-security: square !important;
}
```